# mongodb pointer to another collection's item

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Is it possible to point from one collection's item's value to another collection's item?

example:

```
db.col2.save( { value: 'test' } );
db.col1.save( { title: 'testing, something: [code to point to another collection's item] } );

db.col1.find().toArray()

[
        {
                "_id" : ObjectId([someobjectidhere]),
                "title" : "testing",
                "something": {
                        "value": "test"
                }
        }
]
```

Comment: MongoDB has no joins, so no, not really. Unless you mean referencing? In which case yes but these are not JOINs and are not resolved server-side in any fashion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MongoDB does not support joins. In MongoDB some data is “denormalized,” or stored with related data in documents to remove the need for joins. However, in some cases it makes sense to store related information in separate documents, typically in different collections or databases.

You can refer the doc for [DBRef here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/database-references/)

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can point to another document, however unlike SQL you can't do a join to retrieve both at the same time.
Therefore you would need to do 2 retrieves. One to get the first document (then extract the reference in code) and then use this reference to get the second document